# Symfony not load translation

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony web application written in Symfony 2.8.
All translations work correctly in dev mode ,But the translations of second language not loading in production mode.
If I enable debug in app.php , translations will load completely.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

TO

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

But it is not a good choice.

My config.yml is:

```
parameters:
    locale: fa

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%" , en] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
```

I put the messages.fa.yml and messages.en.yml files in app directory.

Comment: Did you try with `cache:clear --env=prod` ?

Comment: yes!! many times! I also delete the cache folder.

Comment: Where is locate your translation file and service config?

Comment: If you only had `translator: { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }` in config.yml ?

Comment: Translation files was in there bundles and I move theme to app folder to solving problem. But it not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try follow my instructions:

1) Move your trans.yml files into `src->nameBundle->Resources->translations`

2) In src->nameBunndle create or update `DependencyInjection` folder

3) In `DependencyInjection` folder create `Configuration.php` and `NameExtension.php` where name is your name of bundle.

4) Code `Configuration.php` :

```
<?php

namespace NameBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('name'); // name you bundle

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

5) Code `NameExtension.php` :

```
<?php

namespace NameBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class NameExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: All my bundles have DependencyInjection exact the same as you say. And my translations files was in each bundle separately and I move them  to app folder to solve problem but it not solved. Excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: If I change defaultLocale to en , then just English translations work and if I change it to 'fa' , just Persian translations work.(ONLY IN PRODUCTION)